# Glossaries with hyperlinks to external pdf

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

We are making a book, where each chapter is included and compiled together in a single master .tex file. We also compile each chapter separately to make a single .pdf for each chapter, and we can easily make a reference to another chapter using the `xr-hyper` package  (the e.g. section number becomes then a hyperlink, and when pressed the master .pdf opens on the right page).

Now, we would like to do the same with the glossaries, such that when an entry is marked e.g. `\gls{<entry label>}` then when clicked the master .pdf opens at the entry in the glossary of the main .pdf document.

Further, also a version which points to an url of the master .pdf, would be great (like achieved with `xr-hyper` by `\externaldocument{master}[<url>]`.

I can't find out how to do this. Is it possible and how?

Comment: If Nicola Talbot's answer is a solution to your problem consider to accept it, please

Answer (score 1):

It would help to have a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) but assuming a master file called `master.tex` that looks like:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-brief}

\begin{document}

\gls{lorem}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This is compiled in the usual manner:

```
pdflatex master
makeglossaries master
pdflatex master
```

Now a child document:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-brief}

\renewcommand*{\glsdohyperlink}[2]{%
 \hyperref{master.pdf}{}{#1}{#2}%
}

\glsenablehyper

\begin{document}
\gls{lorem}.

\end{document}
```

Assuming this file is called `child.tex` then the build process for this file is:

```
pdflatex child
pdflatex child
```

This will break if you need an internal glossary as well. If you need a mixture of internal and external links, then the simplest method is to use the extension package [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) at least v1.11 (2017-01-19):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}[2017/01/19]

\newignoredglossary*{external}

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries[external]{example-glossaries-brief}

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name=sample,category=internal,
 description={an example}
}

\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{targeturl}{master.pdf}
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{targetname}{\glolinkprefix\glslabel}


\begin{document}
\gls{lorem}, \gls{sample}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The build process is now:

```
pdflatex child
makeglossaries child
pdflatex child
```